# How to redirect to Google Auth in PhoneGap Cordova?

Tags: android, cordova, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-authentication

I'm working on Firebase + PhoneGap. I have made a simple Google Auth login system, it's working perfect on web (smart-media-compaing.firebaseapp.com), but when I make it's APK for Android by PhoneGap, the PhoneGap app(Android) doesn't redirect me to Google Auth page.

Because it wont find any localserver/other server address to work on.

How do I redirect to Google Auth in PhoneGap (Android) app?

```
var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
        provider.setCustomParameters({
          'login_hint': 'user@example.com'
        });

        firebase.auth().signInWithRedirect(provider);

        firebase.auth().getRedirectResult().then(function(result) {
          if (result.credential) {
            // This gives you a Google Access Token. You can use it to access the Google API.
            var token = result.credential.accessToken;
            // ...
              var user = result.user;

                window.location.replace('profile.html');
          }
          // The signed-in user info.
          var user = result.user;
        }).catch(function(error) {
          // Handle Errors here.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          // The email of the user's account used.
          var email = error.email;
          // The firebase.auth.AuthCredential type that was used.
          var credential = error.credential;
          // ...
        });
```

Is it a Firebase problem or a PhoneGap problem?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37937496/cordova-inappbrowser-wont-work-with-firebaseauth/37951797#37951797

Comment: thanks @bojeil i'll be looking at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use the InAppBrowser plugin to open the external website.
https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

Phonegap app runs with `file://` protocol, and HTTP requests always go through the proxy server, maybe the proxy server can't process the auth request successfully.